# Background image for LaunchScreen.storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uistoryboard, launch-screen

I am using a storyboard as launch screen.

It has a full size `UIImageView` for artwork and a language dependent UILabel rendered over it.

I do have .png files for all possible iPhone screen sizes (iPad not necessary).

The artwork contains a circle that looks distorted when I use the same image for iPhone 4s and iPhone 5.

**Approach 1**

In the LaunchScreen.storyboard, I add an `UIImageView` for all iPhones and use an imageSet, that is defined in `Assets.xcassets`.

When I do this, the image@2x of the image set is used for iPhone 4s and for iPhone 5 5s. One of both looks bad, because iPhone 4s and 5 have different heights.

I am not aware that I can use size classes in the storyboard to distinguish between iPhone 4s and iPhone 5. Or can I?

**Approach 2**

create a launch image set in Assets.xcassets, which can hold all necessary image sizes.

I can't select this launch image set in the `UIImageView` as image.

**Question**

In a full size `UIImageView` in a LaunchScreen.storyboard: how do I display different pngs for

- iPhone 4 + 4s 640 x 960 pixels
- iPhone 5 + 5s 640 x 1136 pixels
- iPhone 6 + 6s 750 x 1334 pixels
- iPhone 6 plus + 6s plus 1242 x 2208 pixels (portrait and landscape)

The main problem appears to distinguish between 4 + 4s and 5 + 5s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a circle that looks distorted when I use the same image for iPhone 4s and iPhone 5.

The problem is with the *content mode* of the image view. Use a content mode that does not stretch the image out of its aspect ratio.